# Python 2.7 package install with multiple modules and packaged namespaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, package, setup.py

I want to keep multiple python modules in the same repo so it's easier to manage them, and work on them simultaneously.

The modules are packaged namespace packages, so I can't have the roots at the same level, and there are 4 of them, and might be more later.

Here's the structure I have:

```
repo/
  modules/
    foo_a/
      setup.py
      VERSION
      foo/
        __init__.py
        a/
    foo_b/
      setup.py
      VERSION
      foo/
        __init__.py
        b/
```

The VERSION files are separate and track different versions. And the `__init__.py` files above are [the special type described here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages).

Currently I automatically build the respective module when the VERSION file in it changes.

---

What I want is to be able to install the entire package with all namespace packages from the root of the repo. So I can just do `pip install .`. Either this would install everything as a single package (`foo_all`) or individually install each module.

The usecase for this, is that most people use all modules and they want something easy to install, but sometimes I just want to be able to install one of the modules.

The key thing is that you can run:

```
pip install repo
```

and then these Python commands succeed.

```
from foo import a
from foo import b
```

---

Any ideas on how to do this?

I've seen the [`setuptools.find_namespace_packages()`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) function, but that looks like it's only Python3, and I'm not entirely sure it's what I need anyway. I can't upgrade to Python3 because it's for a client and it's dependent on a Python2 API, which is incredibly frustrating.

Also seen the `package_dir` option for `setuptools.setup()`, but that's for if all the packages are just in a different folder. I can't put all the package in a different folder because the individual files would overlap (`setup.py`, `VERSION`, `foo/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest distributing `foo.a` and `foo.b` as independent projects alongside a `foo` project that serves as some kind of "umbrella project" and has the other two as direct dependencies (in `install_requires`).

The whole setup is described in the [Python Packaging User Guide on "Packaging namespace packages"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521097).